# Define the following three members of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define the following three members of the series: 1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16, 18, 22, 28,...

I can only see that i has something to do with adding 2 but i cant get it.

Answer (score 1):

See how that sequence relates to the famous sequence $$2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29...$$ of consecutive prime numbers.

$$2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29...\\1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16, 18, 22, 28...$$

Comment: Aha i see it now thanks.